# SQL Server : join on array of ID's from previous join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One has been pruned to show only ID's which meet certain criteria. The second needs to be pruned to show only data that matches the previous "array" of id's. there can be multiple results.
Consider the following:

**Query_1_final**: Returns the ID's of users whom meet certain criteria:

```
select 
    t1.[user_id]
from 
    [SQLDB].[db].[meeting_parties] as t1
inner join
    (select distinct 
         [user_id]
     from 
         [SQLDB].[db].[meeting_parties]
     group by 
         [user_id]
     having 
         count([user_id]) = 1) as t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where 
    [type] = 'organiser'
```

This works great and returns:

```
user_id 
--------------------
22
1255
9821
  and so on...
```

It produces a single column with the ID's of everyone who is a "Meeting Organizer" and also in the active_meetings table. (note, there are multiple types/roles, this was the best way to grab them all)

Now, I need this data to filter another table, another join. Here is the start of my query

**Query_2_PREP**: returns 5 columns where the meeting has "started" already.

```
SELECT 
    [meeting_id]
    ,[meeting_style]
    ,[meeting_day]
    ,[address]
    ,[promos]
FROM 
    [SQLDB].[db].[all_meetings]
WHERE 
    [meeting_started] = 'TRUE'
```

This works as well

```
meeting_id | meeting_style | meeting_day ...
---------------------------------------------
23          open             M,F,SA
23          discussion       TU,TH
23          lead             W,F
  and so on...
```

and returns ALL 10,982 meetings that started, but I need it to return only the meetings that are from the distinct 'organiser's ID's from `Query_1_final` (which should be more like 1200 records or so)

Ideally, I need something "like" this below (but of course it does not work)

**Query 2**: needs to return all meetings that are from organiser ID's only.

```
SELECT 
    [meeting_party_id]
    ,[meeting_style]
    ,[meeting_day]
    ,[address]
    ,[promos]
FROM 
    [SQLDB].[db].[all_meetings]
WHERE 
    [meeting_started] = 'TRUE'
    AND [meeting_party_id] = "ANY Query_1_final results, especially multiple"
```

I have tried nesting JOIN and INNER JOIN's but I think there is something fundamental I am missing here about SQL. In PHP I would use an array compare or just run another query... any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IN`.  Here is the structure of the logic:

```
with q1 as (
      <first query here>
     )
SELECT m.*
 FROM [SQLDB].[db].[all_meetings] m
WHERE meeting_started = 'TRUE' AND
      meeting_party_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM q1);
```

Comment: I mistyped.
The "app" indeed takes [t2.user_id] and inserts it into [meeting_party_id] based on user actions. I am trying your solution now...

Comment: Oh yea. That did the trick. You my man are awesome. I owe you a pizza. I see what I was doing wrong now, I was not wrapping/nesting properly. Thank you so much!